# In WCF, how can I modify operation results before the serialization process?

Tags: wcf, serialization

I want to modify all of the operation results before the serialization for security purposes. I have some options:

- I can write my own serializer
- I can write a parameter inspector behavior

I don't want to process raw message, I want to use reflection. Are there any alternative ways?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

- Write a wrapper method that wraps around the results of this processor method
- Insert a custom HTTP or SOAP header in the outgoing message, and watch out for the header in the message encoder, error handler, or message inspector